# N2N-Edge VPN and CentOS server

Tags: xubuntu, internet, proxy, vpn, sharing

I have one big appeal. I'm newguide in configuring iptables etc...

I have at home FreePBX server (on CentOS 6.5) where is installed n2n VPN as service
I will name it [S]  (adress on home LAN 192.168.0.102 and on N2N VPN 192.168.5.110)

And at work I have installed Xubuntu. We will name it [X]

I want to be [X] connected to internet over [S] to internet and back.

For setup I used this manual [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-linux-internet-connection-sharing-howto/) and on [X] i run `ssh -D 8000 root@192.168.5.110`, connected OK.

In Firefox i set proxy on 127.0.0.1 and port 8000, but Firefox returning that server is not responding...

Very thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set proxy of firefox 127.0.0.1:8000 on [X]?
Try to set proxy 192.168.5.110 and port 8000 because that ip is on [S] witch is proxy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But on Centos server is not installed proxy, because I'm using Socks Proxy.

It is not need to have proxy server if I'm connectin via SOCK SSH

Somethink more?

Comment: Maybe I don't urandesten you. X is connected via n2n vpn to S. Right? Traffic flow is X browser -> local socks proxy -> n2n vpn on S -> from S to internet and back. If you wish local socks proxy on X command is ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:8000 localhost. After this command you can put proxy in X browser to 127.0.0.1 and port 8000.

Comment: Yes, X is connected to X via n2n VPN. And I want use Socks proxy from X to S and from S to internet. But I will try your answer and give u feedback. Thanks :)